# SIGSTOP and SIGCONT and the bash choosing how to respond to them

Tags: bash, kernel, signals

I'm reading [the documentation on the freezer-subsystem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/freezer-subsystem.txt) and I came across the following example on why `SIGSTOP` and `SIGCONT` are not always working as we expect them to:

```
$ echo $$
16644
$ bash
$ echo $$
16690


From a second, unrelated bash shell:
$ kill -SIGSTOP 16690
$ kill -SIGCONT 16690

<at this point 16690 exits and causes 16644 to exit too>
```

What I don't understand is the explanation:
"*This happens because bash can observe both signals and choose how it
responds to them.*"
Why can the bash choose here, isn't the command not clearly stating what to do?

Comment: Are you actually asking why both bash processes are *dying*, despite just the child being told to just *stop* and then *continue*, not to *terminate*? Or are you looking for someone to expand on the point of that article (why `SIGSTOP` and `SIGCONT` are inappropriate for "freezing" tasks, etc)

Comment: My naive thinking is: `echo $$` generates a process with the id 16690. Now I would expect that `kill -SIGSTOP 16690` stops this process and `SIGCONT` resumes it. Especially the part where the bash is choosing what to do makes no sense to me.